# What is this dryer part?

Tags: dryer

My dryer was "kathunking" and when I opened it up, I found this wedged between the drum and the side wall.  The dryer is an LG DLE7050V.

The part number on the part itself is 3350EL3007

[image: Dryer part]

[image: Dryer part second angle]

EDIT:
After finding the part number, I was able to determine that is a "Dryer Cover" but can't find it on a diagram where it's supposed to go

Comment: Make and model number, and look up an exploded parts diagram for a matching part.

Comment: The manual for that model shows no parts resembling the image. The image looks like something found in a washing machine for dispensing detergent, bleach or softener. Perhaps it was a misplaced part on the factory floor?

Comment: Looks like a detergent dispenser from your wash machine.

Comment: @fred_dot_u I edited in the part number

Comment: Enter the part number in your favorite search engine, and you'll find many websites identifying the part and offering to sell it to you.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I edited in the Make and Model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your updated question with the part numbers has an answer of sort. [AppliancePartsPros.com](https://www.appliancepartspros.com/lg-cover-guide-3550el3007d-ap5782039.html) has the part number along with the updated part number and a diagram of the part and placement in the machine:

[image: appliance part location image]

Unfortunately, as you can see, the image is of nearly-useless quality. It is the only image I've found for this machine/part number. Perhaps by trial-and-error you can determine the approximate location for the part, once you disassemble your dryer.

The price for the part is under ten dollars, so you may have to purchase a replacement, although your photo appears to show an intact part.

Thanks to the link from Ecnerwal, the image is much clearer.

[image: clearer image]

A560 is the updated part number.

Comment: This unanswered question on a different forum has a better quality closeup which appears to show it "against the top/back" and that it (evidently, I infer) has screws that are probably on the floor under or behind the dryer now, having presumably vibrated loose. https://www.automaticwasher.org/cgi-bin/TD/TD-VIEWTHREAD.cgi?88245

Answer (score 2):

I am in the process of replacing rollers on an LG DLEX7700VE. The same part was attached to the back panel with 2 screws from the outside. It supports the wiring harness and prevents it from being near the drum. In the diagrams it is listed as A560.
The one in mine has a wide notch across the bottom which is where the bundle snakes through. Mine does not have the slot in the side a little smaller than thumb width.